# error: cannot find symbol import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId symbol: class FirebaseInstanceId location package com.google.firebase.iid

Tags: java, android, firebase

I downloaded a project from GitHub to modify but found some errors.
I have to update my firebase details.But after update found error: cannot find symbol import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId; symbol.

My registerActivity.java:

```
package com.vserv.user.activity;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
}
private void upload(final String check) {
FirebaseInstanceId token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance();
        request.setToken(token.getToken());
}
```

my baseapp.java

```
package com.vserv.user.constants;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

import androidx.multidex.MultiDex;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.vserv.user.models.FirebaseToken;
import com.vserv.user.models.User;

import io.realm.Realm;
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration;

/**
 * Created by Ourdevelops Team on 10/13/2019.
 */

public class BaseApp extends Application {

    private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 0;

    private User loginUser;

    private Realm realmInstance;

    public static BaseApp getInstance(Context context) {
        return (BaseApp) context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .schemaVersion(SCHEMA_VERSION)
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();

        FirebaseToken token = new FirebaseToken(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("ouride");
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("customer");
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);

//        realmInstance = Realm.getInstance(config);
        realmInstance = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realmInstance.beginTransaction();
        realmInstance.delete(FirebaseToken.class);
        realmInstance.copyToRealm(token);
        realmInstance.commitTransaction();

        start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    public User getLoginUser() {
        return loginUser;
    }

    public void setLoginUser(User loginUser) {
        this.loginUser = loginUser;
    }

    public final Realm getRealmInstance() {
        return realmInstance;
    }

    private void start() {
        Realm realm = getRealmInstance();
        User user = realm.where(User.class).findFirst();
        if (user != null) {
            setLoginUser(user);
        }
    }

}
```

my firebasetoken.java

```
package com.vserv.user.models;

import io.realm.RealmObject;

/**
 * Created by Ourdevelops Team on 10/13/2019.
 */

public class FirebaseToken extends RealmObject {
    private String tokenId;

    public FirebaseToken(String tokenId) {
        this.tokenId = tokenId;
    }

    public FirebaseToken() {
    }

    public String getTokenId() {
        return tokenId;
    }

    public void setTokenId(String tokenId) {
        this.tokenId = tokenId;
    }
}
```

Tried with watchig you tube videos but not solved.
I am new to androidstudio.
Please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: in Stackoverflow i am unable to provide all the codes due to character limit

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **800** (eight hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Than you for your suggestion.
done editing